# Add 2 days to "Check In Date" on Booking Widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, widget

I have a booking widget on my website which checks the availability of the accommodation on a linked booking website.

I would like to have the "check out date" automatically be '2 days later' than the check in date, unless the user selects otherwise.

Eg: Check in date (entered on calendar by user)    1 September 2016
    Check out date - automatically has a text of 3 September 2016

THis is the code for my iFrame Widget:

```
<div id="booking_widget">
<form class="formtastic" target="_blank" action="/properties/airportgamedirect?locale=en" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="locale" id="locale" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="from_widget" id="from_widget" value="true">
<fieldset class="inputs">
<ol>
<li class="string">
<label>Check In Date</label>
<input type="text" name="check_in_date_view" id="check_in_date_view" class="calendar hasDatepicker" data-init-val="null"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="https://d3ltdu8ywan39g.cloudfront.net/assets/cal_button-27edd7f4d9f9f1a1ef085e5b4e139081.png" alt="Select a date" title="Select a date"><input type="hidden" name="check_in_date" id="check_in_date" value="">
</li>
<li class="string">
<label>Check Out Date</label>
<input type="text" name="check_out_date_view" id="check_out_date_view" class="calendar hasDatepicker" data-init-val="null"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="https://d3ltdu8ywan39g.cloudfront.net/assets/cal_button-27edd7f4d9f9f1a1ef085e5b4e139081.png" alt="Select a date" title="Select a date"><input type="hidden" name="check_out_date" id="check_out_date">
</li>
<li class="select_occupancies">
<label>Adults</label>
<select name="number_adults" id="number_adults"><option value="0">0</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option></select>
</li>
<li class="select_occupancies">
<label>Children</label>
<select name="number_children" id="number_children"><option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option></select>
</li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="actions">
<ol>
<li><input type="submit" name="commit" value=" Check Availability" class="check_availability"></li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
</form>

</div>
```

I have tried

```
<input type="text" name="check_out_date_view" id="check_out_date_view" class="calendar hasDatepicker" data-init-value="text" value="check_in_date">
```

but that just adds the text "check_In_date" instead of the "check_in_date" value from the above field

Comment: you need to use java script to get that to work, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried    `<input type="text" name="check_out_date_view" id="check_out_date_view" class="calendar hasDatepicker" data-init-value="text" value="check_in_date">`  but that just adds the text "check_In_date" instead of the "check_in_date" value from the above field

Answer (score 0):

You have to set and event listener on the check-in date box, once the user pick a date. you update the check-out box, something like this

```
$( "#check_in_date" ).change(function() {

    //add two days
    var checkoutDate = new Date($(this).val)
    checkoutDate.setDate(checkoutDate.getDate() + 2)

    //update check-out input
    $( "#check_out_date" ).val(checkoutDate)
});
```

Comment: I added the above to my "functions.php" of my wordpress file - (using a plugin)    is that correct ?